# What are the biggest shortcomings of the Big Bang theory?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, big-bang

Big bang theory is the most accepted theory by the physicists. It explains about the origin of the universe but what are the loopholes of this theory? Is the loophole about time or space or the origin? Is there any other theory which seriously contradicts big bang theory?

Comment: FYI: "Loophole" usually refers to a defect that was _intentionally_ added to some _human_ law for the express purpose of allowing those in-the-know to circumvent the spirit of the law without actually breaking the law. If you want to describe a defect in a scientific theory, then "defect," or "shortcoming," or "deficiency," or just plain "hole" are all good words.

Comment: @solomon Slow, true it's often about a human law, but the defect didn't have to be 'intentional', just a defect discovered or used by those who want to get around the law

Answer (score 4):

The Big Bang theory plus dark energy, inflation and dark matter - the 'Concordance Cosmology', with all it's variable parameters, is a successful theory making predictions confirmed by experiment - apart from the following:

the Hubble tension - the difference in the Hubble parameter measured locally and that predicted by the theory.

Explanation of the nature of dark matter

Explanation for the beginning and the nature of inflation

Explanation for why inflation ended

Explanation for the nature and beginning of dark energy

The coincidence problem

But apart from that it's a very successful theory!

The Big Bang part of the model is on quite solid ground (compared to the rest of the model), the predictions for the abundancies of the elements are good (apart from the Lithium abundance).

There is the Cosmic Background Radiation and the redshift, so it's likely to be kept in any alternative models.

It becomes dubious when the idea is taken to the extreme of the very beginning of the universe.  Then there are loopholes in Big Bang theory.

There would have to have been a state of infinite pressure and density and that seems unphysical.  Some scientists would prefer that the Big Bang theory is valid for times when the universe was small, but not at a point.

It could be that some little understood physics or law of Quantum Gravity is required to describe the universe at higher densities.  It's possible that the Big Bang was the result of a 'bounce', when the universe collapsed almost to a point - and then the mechanisms mentioned above allowed the 'bounce' to occur.

Comment: "Explanation for the beginning" is the essential phrase in this answer, as there are at least three cosmological models by major physicists, all formulated since 2002, that don't require a beginning for the universe: Aguirre & Gratton's "Steady-state eternal inflation" (vetted as compatible with inflation by Guth, Vilenkin, and Borde, in a footote to the last--2003's--formulation of their BGV Theorem), Nikodem Poplawski's inflationary (but not field-based) "Cosmology with torsion", and the 2020 Nobel winner Penrose's "Conformal cyclic cosmology".

Answer (score 1):

I would not say that it is the 'most accepted theory by the physicists'. First of all, it is not a *theory* in the sense that QFT or General Relativity (GR) is a theory, but it is a *model*. This means we take certain initial conditions and constituents for the early universe and then use the theory GR to make predictions about the evolution of the universe. Some of these predictions fit the observations very well. Second, it is still not even the 'most accepted model', though, if such a thing exists. The most common problems with the standard Big Bang Model *without* inflation are problems with the fine-tuned initial conditions. Why is the universe so uniform (what we see in the CMB) on large scales although not all regions could not have been in causal contact? Also, a big question is why the energy density of the universe is exactly such that it has neither collapsed very fast in the beginning nor is mostly empty by know. Amongst others, both of these problems are solved by *cosmic inflation*, which assumes there was not necessarily a 'Big Bang' (meaning an initial moment, where the universe was *infinitely* dense), but that very early in its history the universe was dominated by a form of energy that made it expand exponentially, which could basically have gone on for a long time.

Comment: There are endless philosophical discussions whether fine tuning should or should not be a physical principle (and IMHO it seems it should not be), rendering your "problems" moot points.

Comment: The theory used in a model is not necessarily GR (which was formulated in 1915):  For instance, the potentially past- and future-eternal "Cosmology with torsion", described in 2010-2021 papers by Nikodem Poplawski that can be found by his name on Cornell University's Arxiv website, is based on the more complex Einstein-Cartan Theory, worked out by Einstein in collaboration with the mathematician Cartan in 1929, a few years after the discovery of particulate spin.